# Using generic types instead of concrete types that are provided to Closure traits in Rust, is this possible?

Tags: generics, rust, closures, traits

So I've been learning rust with help of the rust book and in [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html) chapter (near the ends of it)

They say to introduce more generics to have one closure take multiple types of args and rightfully return many.

> The second problem with the current Cacher implementation is that it only accepts closures that take one parameter of type u32 and return a u32. We might want to cache the results of closures that take a string slice and return usize values, for example. To fix this issue, try introducing more generic parameters to increase the flexibility of the Cacher functionality.

So I was trying something along these lines :

```rs
struct Cacher<T,V>{
    calculation : T,
    value : Option<V>
}

impl<T> Cacher<T,u32>
where
    T : Fn(u32) -> u32,
    //Note Fn is a trait, fn is the usual keyword
{
    fn new(calculation : T) -> Cacher<T,u32>{
        Cacher { calculation, value: None }
    }

    fn get_value(&mut self,args : u32) -> Option<u32>{
        match self.value{
            None => {
                let res = ( self.calculation )(args);
                self.value = Some(res);
                return self.value;
            }
            _ => {
                return self.value;
            }
        }
    }
}


struct BetterCache<T,V>{
    compute_function : T,
    value : Option<V>
}

impl BetterCache<T,V>
where
    T : Fn(V) -> V
{

}
```

BetterCache being the one where I'm trying to implement something different. If this isnt the right way to do it, what is?

Answer (score 1):

Well as always, the rust compiler has come to the rescue...my bad on not having read the error correctly, simply T and V were not in scope of impl,

Simply this fixed the error :

```rs
struct BetterCacher<T,V>{
    calculation : T,
    value : HashMap<V,V>
}

impl<T,V> BetterCacher<T,V> //The first occurences of <T,V> brings it into scope
where
    T : Fn(V) -> V
{
    fn new(calculation : T) -> BetterCacher<T, V>{
        BetterCacher { calculation, value: HashMap::new() }
    }

    /*
     *fn get_or_generate_value(&mut self, arg : V) -> Option(V){
     *    let value_ref = self.value.get_mut()
     *}
     */
}
```